How to make Bokeh pan tool work independently for multiple y-axes?
I'm working with Bokeh and trying to create a plot with multiple y-axes where each axis can be panned independently. Similar to the twin axes example in the Bokeh documentation, but I want the pan/zoom operations to affect only the specific axis being manipulated.
In the above example, we can zoom different axes independently, but when we pan one y-axis, all y-axes move together. What I want is for each y-axis to pan independently, so that when I pan one y-axis, only that axis's range changes.
I've noticed that WheelZoomTool has a zoom_together="none" option that achieves independent zooming for different axes, but I can't find an equivalent functionality for the PanTool.
Is there a way to achieve independent panning for different axes in Bokeh? Or do I need to implement a custom tool?
